# Prime Digit Sums

Tags: ruby, math, primes

So I'm doing one of those programming challenges on HackerRank to help build my skills. (No this is NOT for an interview! The problem I am on is the Prime Digit Sum. (Full description: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/prime-digit-sums/problem) Basically given a value `n`, I am to find all numbers that are n digits long that meet the following three criteria:

- Every 3 consecutive digits sums to a prime number
- Every 4 consecutive digits sums to a prime number
- Every 5 consecutive digits sums to a prime number

See the link for a detailed breakdown...

I've got a basic function that works, problem is that when `n` gets big enough it breaks:

```
#!/bin/ruby
require 'prime'

def isChloePrime?(num)
    num = num.to_s
    num.chars.each_cons(5) do |set|
        return false unless Prime.prime?(set.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + i.to_i})
    end
    num.chars.each_cons(4) do |set|
        return false unless Prime.prime?(set.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + i.to_i})
    end
    num.chars.each_cons(3) do |set|
        return false unless Prime.prime?(set.inject(0) {|sum, i| sum + i.to_i})
    end
    return true
end

def primeDigitSums(n)
    total = 0
    (10**(n-1)..(10**n-1)).each do |i| 
       total += 1 if isChloePrime?(i)
    end
    return total
end

puts primeDigitSums(6) # prints 95 as expected
puts primeDigitSums(177779) # runtime error
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Not necessarily looking for a "here's the answer". Ideally would love a "try looking into using this function...".

**UPDATE** here is version 2:

```
#!/bin/ruby
require 'prime'

@primes = {}

def isChloePrime?(num)
  num = num.to_s
  (0..num.length-5).each do |i|
    return false unless @primes[num[i,5]]
  end
  return true
end

def primeDigitSums(n)
  total = 0
  (10**(n-1)...(10**n)).each do |i|
    total += 1 if isChloePrime?(i)
  end
  return total
end

(0..99999).each do |val|
    @primes[val.to_s.rjust(5, "0")] = true if [3,4,5].all? { |n| val.digits.each_cons(n).all? { |set| Prime.prime? set.sum } }
end
```

Comment: if you set a debug point maybe you figure out which actual line of code is triggering the runtime... maybe that specific number causes some mathematical issues in some of your lines

Comment: Just a tip, but [`Integer#digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) would be much nicer than converting to a string and splitting into "char" array, and then converting those "chars" back into an integer.

Comment: One Ruby convention (that pretty much all Ruby coders adopt) is to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for names of variables and methods (e.g., `is_chloe_prime?`).

Comment: @ForeverZer0, I'm playing around with some of these...`Integer#digits` is taking like a full minute for `10**177778` (the first number of the one that breaks) and is near instant if you use `to_s.chars`

Comment: @SimpleLime Very odd, but in that case `to_s.chars` would definitely be the way to go. Yet another scenario where large integer break Ruby. Same happens within other methods of `prime.rb` for large numbers. Should probably submit a bug report, as looking at the source, it appears that is SHOULD behave as expected with large numbers, but it doesn't.

Comment: Zack, my answer was wrong, as you suspected. I don't know what I was thinking when I said the first step would be to construct a hash `h` such that `h[t]` is the number of numbers with `n` digits whose digits sum to `t`. That makes no sense. I did a bit of further exploration and found that Hackerrank classes the problem as one whose solution employs dynamic programming. [Here](https://kimiyuki.net/writeup/algo/hackerrank/world-codesprint-8-prime-digit-sums/) is one such implementation.

Comment: I don't follow your revised code, in part because the two methods are not executed. However, it still has the problem that, when `n = 4*10**4` (for example), `primeDigitSums(n)` requires that a colossal number of numbers having `n` digits be examined to determine if they have the required properties. You need to test it yourself to see if it's working, and if it isn't, why. I think you've run the course with your question. It's a hard problem.

Comment: I submitted my code to Hankerrank. While it passed he first test (`n=6`) it failed the second test, which was for a much larger value of `n`, due to an unspecified syntax error . The fact that it clearly would be testing for values of `n` greater than 100,000 tells me that I'm missing some combinatorial aspect of the problem. I'll continue to think about it but for now I've come to a dead end.

Comment: Zack, I revised my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I regard every non-negative integer to be *valid* if the sum of every sequence of 3, 4 and 5 of its digits form a prime number.

**Construct set of relevant prime numbers**

We will need to determine if the sums of digits of 3-, 4- and 5-digit numbers are prime. The largest number will therefore be no larger than `5 * 9`. It is convenient to construct a set of those primes (a set rather than an array to speed lookups).

```
require 'prime'
require 'set'

primes = Prime.each(5*9).to_set
  #=> #<Set: {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43}>
```

**Construct transition hash**

`valid1` is a hash whose keys are all 1-digit numbers (all of which are valid). The value of the key `0` is an array of all 1-digit numbers. For `1-9` the values are arrays of 2-digit numbers (all of which are valid) that are obtained by appending a digit to the key. Collectively, the values include all 2-digit numbers.

```
valid1 = (0..9).each_with_object({}) { |v1,h|
  h[v1] = 10.times.map { |i| 10 * v1 + i } }
```

`valid2` is a hash that maps 2-digit numbers (all valid) to arrays of valid 3-digit numbers that are obtained by appending a digit to the 2-digit number. Collectively, the values include all valid 3-digit numbers. All values are non-empty arrays.

```
valid2 = (10..99).each_with_object({}) do |v2,h|
  p = 10 * v2
  b, a = v2.digits
  h[v2] = (0..9).each_with_object([]) { |c,arr|
    arr << (p+c) if primes.include?(a+b+c) }
end
```

Note that [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) returns an array with the 1's digit first.

`valid3` is a hash that maps valid 3-digit numbers to arrays of valid 4-digit numbers that are obtained by appending a digit to the key. Collectively, the values include all valid 4-digit numbers.  152 of the 303 values are empty arrays.

```
valid3 = valid2.values.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |v3,h|
  p = 10 * v3
  c, b, a = v3.digits
  h[v3] = (0..9).each_with_object([]) do |d,arr|
    t = b+c+d
    arr << (p+d) if primes.include?(t) && primes.include?(t+a)
  end
end
```

`valid4` is a hash that maps valid 4-digit numbers to arrays of valid 4-digit numbers that are obtained by appending a digit to the key and dropping the first digit of key. `valid5.values.flatten.size #=> 218` is the number of valid 5-digit numbers. 142 of the 280 values are empty arrays.

```
valid4 = valid3.values.flatten.each_with_object({}) do |v4,h|
  p = 10 * v4
  d, c, b, a = v4.digits
  h[v4] = (0..9).each_with_object([]) do |e,arr|
    t = c+d+e
    arr << ((p+e) % 10_000) if primes.include?(t) &&
      primes.include?(t += b) && primes.include?(t + a)
  end
end
```

We merge these four hashes to form a single hash `@transition`. The former hashes are no longer needed. `@transition` has 294 keys.

```
@transition = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4].reduce(:merge)
  #=> {0=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  #    1=>[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
  #    ...
  #    9=>[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],
  #    10=>[101, 102, 104, 106], 11=>[110, 111, 113, 115, 119], 
  #    ...
  #    97=>[971, 973, 977], 98=>[980, 982, 986], 99=>[991, 995],
  #    101=>[1011], 102=>[1020], 104=>[], 106=>[], 110=>[1101], 
  #    ...
  #    902=>[9020], 904=>[], 908=>[], 911=>[9110], 913=>[], 917=>[],
  #    1011=>[110], 1020=>[200], 1101=>[], 1110=>[], 1200=>[],
  #    ...
  #    8968=>[], 9020=>[200], 9110=>[], 9200=>[]}
```

**Transition method**

This is the method that will be used to update `counts` each time `n`, the number of digits, is incremented by one.

```
def next_counts(counts)
  counts.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),new_valid|
    @transition[k].each do |new_v|
      (new_valid[new_v] = new_valid[new_v].to_i + v) if @transition.key?(k)
    end
  end
end
```

**`prime_digit_sum` method**

```
def prime_digit_sum(n)
  case n
  when 1 then 10
  when 2 then 90
  when 3 then @transition.sum { |k,v| (10..99).cover?(k) ? v.size : 0 }
  else
    counts = @transition.select { |k,_| (100..999).cover?(k) }.
                         values.flatten.product([1]).to_h   
    (n - 4).times { counts = next_counts(counts) }
    counts.values.sum % (10**9 + 7)
  end
end
```

Note that, for `n = 4` the hash `counts` has keys that are valid 4-digit numbers and values that all equal `1`:

```
counts = @transition.select { |k,_| (100..999).cover?(k) }.
  values.flatten.product([1]).to_h   
  #=> {1011=>1, 1020=>1, 1101=>1, 1110=>1, 1200=>1, 2003=>1, 2005=>1,
  #    ...
  #    8902=>1, 8920=>1, 8968=>1, 9020=>1, 9110=>1, 9200=>1}

counts.size
  #=> 280
```

As shown, for `n >= 5`, `counts` is updated each time `n` is incremented by one. The sum of the values equals the number of valid `n-digit` numbers.

The number formed by the last four digits of every valid `n`-digit numbers is one of `count`'s keys. The value of each key is an array of numbers that comprise the last four digits of all valid `(n+1)`-digit numbers that are produced by appending a digit to the key.

Consider, for example, the value of `counts` for `n = 6`, which is found to be the following.

```
counts
  #=> {1101=>1, 2003=>4, 2005=>4, 300=>1, 302=>1, 304=>1, 308=>1, 320=>1,
  #    322=>1, 326=>1, 328=>1, 380=>1, 382=>1, 386=>1, 388=>1, 500=>1,
  #    502=>1, 506=>1, 508=>1, 560=>1, 562=>1, 566=>1, 568=>1, 1200=>7,
  #    3002=>9, 3020=>4, 3200=>6, 5002=>6, 9200=>4, 200=>9, 1020=>3, 20=>3,
  #    5200=>4, 201=>2, 203=>2, 205=>2, 209=>2, 5020=>2, 9020=>1}
```

Consider the key `2005` and note that

```
@transition[2005]
  #=> [50, 56]
```

We see that there are `4` valid 6-digit numbers whose last four digits are `2005` and that, for each of those `4` numbers, a valid number is produced by adding the digits `0` and `6`, resulting in numbers whose last 5-digits are `20050` and `20056`. However, we need only keep the last four digits, `0050` and `0056`, which are the numbers `50` and `56`. Therefore, when recomputing `counts` for `n = 7`--call it `counts7`--we add `4` to both `counts7[50]` and `counts7[56]`. Other keys `k` of `counts` (for `n=6`) may be such that `@transition[k]` have values that include `50` and `56`, so they too would contribute to `counts7[50]` and `counts7[50]`.

**Selective results**

Let's try it for various values of `n`

```
puts "digits  nbr valid*  seconds"
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 50, 100, 1_000, 10_000, 40_000].each do |n|
  print "%6d" % n
  t = Time.now
  print "%11d" % prime_digit_sum(n)
  puts "%10f" % (Time.now-t).round(4)
end
puts "\n* modulo (10^9+7)"

digits  nbr valid*  seconds
     1         10  0.000000
     2         90  0.000000
     3        303  0.000200
     4        280  0.002200
     5        218  0.000400
     6         95  0.000400
    20      18044  0.000800
    50  215420656  0.001400
   100  518502061  0.002700
  1000  853799949  0.046100
 10000  590948890  0.474200
 40000  776929051  2.531600
```

Comment: Incredibly detailed and helpful response!! Thank you!

Comment: re-reading this you lost me a little bit in the second paragraph. The whole issue is that the function fails when n gets larger that 10 (or at least timesout) Even building that hash would fail...

Comment: This is an amazingly detailed response again, unfortunately it does not work... I know for a fact there are 95 six-digit numbers that satisfy the requirements and this solution gives me a vastly different answer.

Comment: Zack, I'm still working on it and have done several changes since my last edit. I hope to have a revision tonight I'll submit it to Hackerrank when I'm finished. Do you have any other known results besides their being 95 6-digit numbers? See if you can find any problems with the logic of my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem by pre-calculating a list of all the allowed 5-digit sub-sequences: '00002' fails while '28300' is allowed etc.  This could perhaps be set up as a binary array or hash set.

Once you have the list, then you can check any number by moving a 5-digit frame over the number one step at a time.

Comment: great idea... I tried that with my second solution but still timing out. :-(

Comment: The problem is that there are about `0.9*10**n` numbers to check, each having `n` digits, where `n` can be as large as 40,000. Pre-calculating numbers having 3, 4 and 5 digits that are primes is an interesting start, however.

Comment: Check the first (or last) five digits against the pre-calculated list.  If it fails, then you can drop that whole number -- there is no need to check it any further.  If it passes, then shift along one and check those five digits.  The size of the overall number only matters if it passes, or if it only fails near the end.  That should be a relatively small proportion of the total range to check.

Comment: No matter how little time it takes to examine most numbers, there are as many as (approximately)`0.9*10**40000` numbers to examine.